# Select column dynamically in Pandas dataframe based on values in a list or another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this -

| Col1 | Col2 | INDX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 0 |
| 30 | 40 | 1 |
| 50 | 60 | 1 |
| 70 | 80 | 0 |

For each row I want to select value from either Col1 or Col2 based on value in INDX. So the output in above case should be-
[10,40,60,70]

I did this by looping through each row of dataframe, but it's quite slow. Is there is a faster way to accomplish this?

Dummy test code -

```
for i in np.arange(0, df.shape[0]):
    print(df.iloc[i, df['INDX'][i]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `lookup`:

```
cols = df.columns[:2]

df.lookup(df.index, cols[df.INDX])
```

Output:

```
array([10, 40, 60, 70])
```

---

**Update** As commented by Scott, `lookup` is deprecated. We can resolve to numpy indexing:

```
df[cols].to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), df['INDX']]
```

Comment: FYI lookup is deprecated in 1.2. (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#deprecations)

Comment: Read through these issues on pandasdev github.  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39171

Comment: Can't help putting a [comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35224#discussion_r564046976) in the issue on Github.